# Using FAO Geonetwork Data WFS or WCS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, ogc, wcs

Does anyone know how to connect to FAO Geonetwork Server (https://data.apps.fao.org/map/catalog/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?facet.q=type%2Fdataset) as Web Feature Service (WFS) or Web Coverage Service (WCS) in QGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the CSW endpoint for the GeoNetwork instance to QGIS using `Web > MetaSearch`

> Name: FAO Map Catalog
>
> URL: https://data.apps.fao.org/map/catalog/srv/eng/csw?

Then use the search tool to look for services such as  WMS/WFS/WCS to view and /or download the data